# Why Vuex state return array as an object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am using Typescript + vue + vuex, the state is defined as

```html
const state: CommonDataState = {
  clients: [],
  version: 1
}
```

The getters is

```html
const getters: GetterTree<CommonDataState, RootState> = {
  getClients: state=> () => { return state.clients; },
  getClientById: state => (id: string) => { return state.clients.filter(x => true)[0]; },
  getVersion: state => (): Number => { return state.version; }
}
```

While invoking the getter getClientById,

> Error in render: "TypeError: state.clients.filter is not a function"

When I print state.clients with console.log(), it shows that the result is an object with a default property as array instead of an Array type

```
{__esModule: true, __ob__: Observer}
default : Array(15)
__esModule : true
__ob__ : Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get default : ƒ reactiveGetter()
set default : ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__ : Object
```

the default value is the correct array.
However, when I try to change the getter to

```html
  getClientById: state => (id: string) => { return state.clients.default.filter(x => true)[0]; },
```

it return an error

> [ts] Property 'default' does not exist on type 'Client[]'.

So, anyone know what caused this error? and any solution for that?

Comment: You can get the array by using JSON.stringify and JSON parse: `getClientById: state => (id: string) => { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.clients)).filter(x => true)[0]; }`.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://github.com/mrcrowl/vuex-typex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  Change to this structure

```
import { GetterTree, Getter } from 'vuex'
import { State } from './index'

const cartProducts: Getter<State, any> = (state: State) => {
  return state.cart.added.map(shape => {
    // ...
  })
}

const getterTree: GetterTree<State, any> = {
  cartProducts
}

export default getterTree
```

Comment: `Getter<State, any>`why did you put any in place of RootState? the correct one should not be `Getter<State, RootState>`? I really don't understand why RootState should be, and the danger of not having